# Best way to do a IIF conditional with subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a select with subquery inside like

```
SELECT
....
 , (SELECT TOP 1
                        [DDC].[ContractedAmount]
                        FROM @CustomersTable AS [DDC]
                        WHERE [DDC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]) AS [Contracted Amount]
     FROM....
```

But sometimes value of this select can be `0.00` so I want to add conditional if it's 0.00 just return NULL, so I do an `IIF` conditional like:

```
     , IIF((SELECT TOP 1
                            [DDC].[ContractedAmount]
                            FROM @CustomersTable AS [DDC]
                            WHERE [DDC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]) = 
                            0.00,
                            NULL,
           (SELECT TOP 1
                            [DDC].[ContractedAmount]
                            FROM @CustomersTable AS [DDC]
                            WHERE [DDC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey])) AS [Contracted Amount]
```

But as you can see I need to do another subquery in subquery, so I think this is not the best practice to achieve that? is there another way to do this more easy and readeable. Any suggestions? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`NULLIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal.

```
SELECT ...
  NULLIF((subquery), 0.00) AS [Contracted Amount]
```

---

Another way is to use `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT ...,
    IIF(sub.ContractedAmount = 0.00, NULL, sub.ContractedAmount) AS [Contracted Amount]
FROM tab
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [DDC].[ContractedAmount]
            FROM @CustomersTable AS [DDC]
            WHERE [DDC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey])) sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `where` clause to the subquery:

```
(SELECT TOP 1 [DDC].[ContractedAmount]
 FROM @CustomersTable AS [DDC]
 WHERE [DDC].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey] AND
       [DDC].[ContractedAmount] <> 0
) AS [Contracted Amount]
```

If no rows are returned then the value in the outer query is `NULL`.